# How to check different run times of a task in a DAG in an External Sensor Airflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Imagine I have a **DAG A** including some tasks, and these tasks depend on some external sensor on another task in **DAG B**.

For example I want to check the state of a task in **DAG B** on **10:00**, and if this run is succeeded, then the tasks in **DAG A** can run.
But now because of a reason, the task in **DAG B** on **10:00** is failed, but the run of the same task on **11:00** is succeeded.

The problem is the tasks in **DAG A** will pend forever because the task in **DAG B** failed at **10:00**. But it's ok if the next run has run successfully.

How can I implement such a thing in external sensor airflow that check the state of the next run time in another DAG and if it's succeeded, then my tasks can run without a problem?

P.S: because of some reasons I can't use retry!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. It maybe not the best approach, but it works.
In this case we can define a function for `on_failure_callback` and set a **timeout** for our **ExternalSensor**, and when the timeout is reached, we check the next run of the task in the other **DAG** and if it is succeeded, we set the status of our **ExternalSensor** to `SUCCESS` so the other tasks that are depended on this sensor can run without a problem.
This is the code for this approach:

```
from airflow.utils.state import State
from airflow.sensors.external_task_sensor import ExternalTaskSensor
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowSensorTimeout
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from airflow.api.common.experimental.get_task_instance import get_task_instance
from dateutil.parser import parse
from functools import partial

def _failure_callback(task_id, dag_id, execution_date, context):
    if isinstance(context['exception'], AirflowSensorTimeout):
        sensor_instance = context['task_instance']
        next_execution_date = parse(context['ts']) + -(execution_date) + timedelta(hours=1)
        ti = get_task_instance(dag_id=dag_id, task_id=task_id, execution_date=next_execution_date)
        if ti.current_state() == 'success':
            sensor_instance.set_state(State.SUCCESS)



sensor = ExternalTaskSensor(external_task_id='external_task_id',
                              task_id='sensor',
                              external_dag_id='external_dag_id',
                              execution_delta=timedelta(hours=-24) + timedelta(minutes=-30),
                              timeout=5,
                              on_failure_callback=partial(_failure_callback, 'external_task_id', 'external_dag_id', timedelta(hours=-24) + timedelta(minutes=-30)),
                              dag=dag)
```